# How to list all files in a specific directory that starts with 'sh' including inode number in one line

Tags: grep, find, ls

Assuming I'm in the home directory

I'm trying to list all the files in `/etc` to show all files that start with `sh` along with the `inode` number

I tried the following:

```
sudo find /etc -name 'sh*'
# this works but without the inode

ls - '/etc' -i | grep 'sh*'
# this command gets the inode but includes all files that contain 'sh' not starts with
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
find /etc -name 'sh*' -printf '%i %f\n'
```

or (if you don't need to descend into subdirectories)

```
stat -c '%i %n' /etc/sh*
```

or even

```
ls -1i /etc/sh*
```

From `man ls`:

> ```
>    -i, --inode
>           print the index number of each file
> ```

Comment: thank you, is there any way to do that with `ls`?

Comment: @AliKleit please see edit